# Расположение виджет в customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Всем здравствуйте! Хочу попросить помощи более опытных товарищей!
Вопрос следующий: есть приложение, торговый терминал для биржи Deribit.

[image]

размещение и компоновка всех виджетов осуществлялась методом grid(). Но, при открытии приложения на ПК с другими разрешениями, происходит сдвиг виджетов в разные стороны, то уменьшение, то увеличение, как самого окна, так и виджетов в нём.

[image]

При расширении окна, не меняют своего положения и виджеты.
Как эту проблему устранить?
Чтобы виджеты и само окно было адаптивно под любое разрешение мониторов.

размер окна задаётся так:

```
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# Set the width and height of the root window as a percentage of the screen resolution
width_percentage = 0.5
height_percentage = 0.7
width = int(screen_width * width_percentage)
height = int(screen_height * height_percentage)

# Set the geometry of the root window
root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{int(screen_width * (1 - width_percentage) / 2)}+{int(screen_height * (1 - height_percentage) / 2)}")
```

Это решило вопрос с размером самого кона, но теперь вопрос остаётся к виджетам, потому что на меньшем разрешении, все виджеты внутри окна кратно уменьшаются

Предложенное решение в комментариях помогло частично.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это помогло решить вопрос расширениями и привязкой в разрешению экрана. Но так же не решает вопрос с размерами виджетов внутри окна.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522051/python-tkinter-responsive-grid